# Look up cities and localities within a given radius using google maps api

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile

So i'm doing a project in kotlin where i need to implement the google maps api and i need search for every locality, city or county around a given location and within a maximum radius of 50KM

I already built a function to find the actual location of the device but now i have to build the function that searches around that location.

I've already tried a bunch of methods but i can't find out how to make the request or how to read the response and parse it to a list so i can return a list of those loactions

Please help me, im desperate

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Places API from Google. It has the radius functionality.